# JFrame not resized to fit JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I've mocked up a quick GUI for a project, I can see the labels and text fields, but for some reason the window isn't re-sized to what it contains.

Here's the basic run-down:

Creating the JFrame and adding the JPanel:

```
   JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Hotel Reservation App");
   frame1.getContentPane().add(rViewPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   frame1.pack();
   frame1.setVisible(true);
```

This is the JPanel code for the rViewPan:

```
 private void initComponents() {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    arrivalDateTF = new JTextField();


    departureDateTF = new JTextField();
    roomCategoryTF = new JTextField();
    roomQtyTF = new JTextField();

    JTextField[] textFields = { arrivalDateTF, departureDateTF, roomCategoryTF, roomQtyTF };
    JLabel[] textLabels = { new JLabel("1 : "), new JLabel("2 : "),
            new JLabel("3 : "), new JLabel("4 : ")
    };

    JPanel displayPan = new JPanel();
    GridBagLayout gridBagLay = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints gridBagC = new GridBagConstraints();

    displayPan.setLayout(gridBagLay);
    SwingUtilities.addTextElementsAsRows(textLabels, textFields, gridBagLay, displayPan);

    gridBagC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    gridBagC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gridBagC.weightx = 1.0;

    displayPan.add(new JLabel(" "), gridBagC);

    submitB = new JButton("Soumettre");
    displayPan.add(submitB, gridBagC);

    SwingUtilities.addStdBorder(displayPan, "Reservation");
    add(displayPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
```

I basically get a window that's sized to the proper height, but the fields are hidden horizontally.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ..the window isn't re-sized to what it contains.

This variant is.

[image: TestGui]

If you cannot figure how to make your GUI behave, I suggest you make & post an SSCCE.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

// TODO don't extend JPanel, just create an instance
class TestGui extends JPanel {

    JTextField arrivalDateTF;
    JTextField departureDateTF;
    JTextField roomCategoryTF;
    JTextField roomQtyTF;
    JButton submitB;

    TestGui() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        arrivalDateTF = new JTextField(6);
        departureDateTF = new JTextField(6);
        roomCategoryTF = new JTextField(8);
        roomQtyTF = new JTextField(2);

        JTextField[] textFields = { arrivalDateTF, departureDateTF, roomCategoryTF, roomQtyTF };
        JLabel[] textLabels = { new JLabel("1 : "), new JLabel("2 : "),
            new JLabel("3 : "), new JLabel("4 : ")
        };

        JPanel displayPan = new JPanel();
        GridBagLayout gridBagLay = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gridBagC = new GridBagConstraints();

        displayPan.setLayout(gridBagLay);
//      SwingUtilities.addTextElementsAsRows(textLabels, textFields, gridBagLay, displayPan);
        for (int ii=0; ii<textFields.length; ii++) {
            displayPan.add( textLabels[ii] );
            displayPan.add( textFields[ii] );
        }

        gridBagC.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        gridBagC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        gridBagC.weightx = 1.0;

        displayPan.add(new JLabel(" "), gridBagC);

        submitB = new JButton("Soumettre");
        displayPan.add(submitB, gridBagC);

//      SwingUtilities.addStdBorder(displayPan, "Reservation");
        add(displayPan, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Hotel Reservation App");
                frame1.getContentPane().add(new TestGui(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                frame1.pack();
                frame1.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I've managed to get it in working order. For some reason I had a private redefined version of setPreferredSize that wasn't doing anything so the call was pointless. After adding more content to other sections of the main BorderLayout it started behaving correctly.

Comment: *"I had a private redefined version of setPreferredSize"*  Which would have been in the SSCCE if you had chosen to post it.  ;)  Glad you got it sorted.  The best advice I can offer at this instant is that if you think you need to call or override the preferred size of a component, come to SO for assistance first.  :)

Comment: @Andrew Thompson do you know from where became customizations os SwingUtilities2, meaning code line SwingUtilities.addTextElementsAsRows

Comment: @mKorbel  I guessed it is a poorly named custom utility class.  But then, that is the best WAG I can make, short of seeing an..  do I even need to finish that statement?  ;)